# Removing Trailing Periods in MySQL Field

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have a MySQL database called arch, with a table called resources, which has a text field called title. I'm working on normalizing the title field; sometimes it ends with a period, sometimes it doesn't. I'd like to remove all trailing periods. I'm afraid of using the replace function because the title field does contain valid periods within the data.

I've tried using

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM 'title')
```

but am not having luck. I think this must be simple. Shouldn't this be possible within MySQL?

EDIT:

I read elsewhere that TRIM() does not work on SELECT function. I rewrote the statement into

```
UPDATE resources SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM title)
```

and success!

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the data type for the field you want to alter?  Sounds like you need to use SUBSTRING/etc

Comment: @OMGPonies -- I've tried SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM resources.title) and several similar statements. The datatype is text, but I'm going to have repeat this in another field that is varchar(255).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- Sorry, the question should say periods, I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

How have you used `trim()`? It should work, by specifying what characters to trim;

```
select trim(trailing '.' from `your_column`)...
```

Edit,

You're not referencing a column when you use `trim()`, you're pointing to a string. Remove the single quotes, or replace them with ticks (`).

Comment: I have, but I get this error, "#1054 - Unknown column 'title' in 'field list'". And resources definitely has a field called title.

Comment: @Nathan - please update your original question with code sample and the layout of your table. Trim() definitely works, something else is probably causing your error.

Comment: Both SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM `title`) and SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM title) result in the same error as before. I've tried resouces.title, thinking I needed to specify the table first, but that doesn't work either.